# System.IO.FileNotFoundException:'Could not load file or assembly '*, Version=7.0.0.0..,'The system cannot find the file specified' on .NET6&7 Project

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, reference, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I'm getting the following error when I run my project which is build by **.NET6 Web API** into my existing applications which are stable version and build by **.NET6** and **net48** as the target frameworks.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have created a couple of Web API projects. One is **.NET6** and another is **.NET7** as the target frameworks. Both are working fine independently when I run outside of my existing application.

When I move the projects inside of an existing applications I'm always getting the **Could not load file or assembly** errors for all of the dependent packages in the project.

Here are the project configuration of my existing applications.

**.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**global.json**

```
   {
      "sdk": {
        "version": "7.0.102",
        "rollForward": "latestFeature"
      }
    }
```

I have installed **net48**,**.NET SDK** **7.0.102** and **6.0.300** on my machine.

I cross checked and tried all the possible ways to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What is the target runtime you are adding these projects to? Do you also have .NET Framework 4.8 installed? You have it as one of the target frameworks, but not mentioned as installed on the machine.

Have you seen the following thread, which might be helpful?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183067/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-ver